# High pass filter with given attenuation

Tags: capacitor, resistors, filter

Choose a frequency \$f_0\$.We have to project a circuit such as:

1. all the \$f \ge 10f_0\$ can pass without attenuation
2. **all** the \$f \le \frac{1}{10} f_0\$ pass with an attenuation of a factor of 10.

The solution is giving by

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsOXxR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but I can't understand why. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, think of the capacitor as a frequency-dependent resistor.

At high frequencies, you can think of it as a dead short relative to the fixed resistance.  In that case, the input is simply connected to the output, so the gain is 1.

At low frequencies, the capacitor is a open circuit.  Now you only have the two resistors forming a voltage divider with a gain of 1/11.  Whoever said this had a low frequency gain of 1/10 was wrong, unless they consider 1/11 within their error margin.  Note that the gain of the voltage divider is:

gain = R / (10R + R) = R / 11R = 1/11

To find the crossover frequency of a R-C filter, you set the impedance magnitude of the capacitor equal to the resistance:

R = 1 / (2πfC)

When f is in units of Hz, C in Farads, then R is in Ohms.

Comment: Could you explain me why, at low frequencies, the capacitor is an open circuit?

Comment: If I consider a frequency like 10 Hz and a C=47nF, according to \$Z=\frac{1}{\omega * C}\$, I obtain a very heigh impedence.. where am I wronging? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @sunri: Look at the equation I showed for the impedance magnitude of a capacitor.  R becomes infinite as C goes to 0.

Comment: "Open circuit" means that the resistence is infinite.. isn't it?

Comment: If, at low frequencies, the capacitor is like a very high resistor, the current doesn't pass through it and passes through the two resistors. Is this step correct? Now, I know that if I consider a "normal" high pass filter, all low frequencies are attenuated, sometimes they are attenuated a lot. Is this strong attenuation due to the fact that a very little current passes through the capacitor? And, in our circuit, is the attenuation of a factor of 10 due to the fact that much more current passes through the resistor R1=10R than the current that passes through the capacitor?

Comment: And, this is the last question: is the cutoff frequency given by \$f_o=\frac {1}{2 \pi (R1//R)C}\$?

Comment: Could you answer me? I'll be very grateful! Thank you so much

Comment: @sunri: You keep asking things I already went over in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't understood your answer about the cutoff frequency